# Trying to implement the okHttp Call & Callback scenario. Upon completion there is no onPostExecute to modify the UI

Tags: android, user-interface, response, okhttp

Previously I would simply pass the `response.body().string()` to `OnPostExecute()` method of an `asyncTask` to update `TextViews` of the `UI`. `okHttp` doesn't seem to have this option. Where is the equivalent or how to achieve this?

```
//Call to server to echo MySQL query
     private void usersInZone() {
                if (!isNetworkAvailable()) return;
                rotate(true);
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add("userId", String.valueOf(userId))
                        .add("channel", String.valueOf(subport + port))
                        .build();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(SITE_URL + "inZone.php")
                        .post(formBody)
                        .build();

                Call users = client.newCall(request);
                users.enqueue(caller);
            }

//okHttp Callback to parse echo response
    caller = new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    if (RS != null) RS.makePoor(true);
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    LOG.l(String.valueOf(call));
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject data = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                            updateFields(getString(R.string.inzone) + data.getInt("total") + "]", String.valueOf(data.getInt("zone")));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            LOG.l("JSONException" + e);
                        }
                    } else if (RS != null) RS.makePoor(true);

                }
            };
//UI textViews i'm needing to update with the echoed results
    private void updateFields(String total, String channelTotal){
            subtitle.setText(total);
            tvusercount.setText(channelTotal);
        }
```

Comment: AFAIK, `onResponse()` is called on the main application thread. You can update your UI there.

Comment: getting this error...android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: Well, I don't know how you are creating the views. If we assume that they are created conventionally (i.e., on the main application thread), then you can use `runOnUiThread()` (called on an `Activity`) or `post()` (called on a `View`) to execute your `updateFields()` on the main application thread. I know that Retrofit delivers its asynchronous results on the main application thread; I was under the impression that OkHttp did too, though I think I have only used its synchronous API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback is not called on the main thread.  If you need to update the UI, a simple way to do that is to create a class that implemented `Callback` and post the items to the UI like so:

```
  public abstract class UIMainCallback implements Callback {
    private static final Handler mUIHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    abstract void failure(Request request, IOException e);

    abstract void response(Response response);

    @Override
    public void onFailure(final Request request, final IOException e) {
        mUIHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                failure(request, e);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(final Response response) throws IOException {
        mUIHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                response(response);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then your `Caller` can just implement the UIMainCallback instead of the interface.

Answer (score 2):

> Where is the equivalent or how to achieve this?

OkHttp's `onResponse()` is not called on main thread. If you want to update UI in onResponse you must delegate this task to UI thread. Using `Handler` and posting `Runnable` is one way of doing so.